# How to customise combobox button look in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox

Just wondering if anyone knows how to change the look of the button on a wpf combobox?
In case you are wondering I just want to change the shape of it and the background.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily modify the ControlTemplate or style of controls using Expression Blend.

Here is one example which will use the Simple Style for the ComboBox and i have modified the Toggle button Color to red.

```
  <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="1.0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="0.0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="1.0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <!-- LightBrush is used for content areas such as Menu, Tab Control background -->
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LightBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="1.0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <!-- MouseOverBrush is used for MouseOver in Button, Radio Button, CheckBox -->
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MouseOverBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#AAA" Offset="1.0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <!-- PressedBrush is used for Pressed in Button, Radio Button, CheckBox -->
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#BBB" Offset="0.0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.9"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="1.0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBorderBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="0.0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#888" Offset="1.0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <!-- SelectedBackgroundBrush is used for the Selected item in ListBoxItem, ComboBoxItem-->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBackgroundBrush" Color="#DDD"/>

    <!-- Disabled Brushes are used for the Disabled look of each control -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="#EEE"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBorderBrush" Color="#AAA"/>

    <!-- Used for background of ScrollViewer, TreeView, ListBox, Expander, TextBox, Tab Control -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF"/>

    <!-- DefaultedBorderBrush is used to show KeyBoardFocus -->
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DefaultedBorderBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#777" Offset="0.0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#000" Offset="1.0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidBorderBrush" Color="#888"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightBorderBrush" Color="#AAA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightColorBrush" Color="#DDD"/>

    <!-- Used for Checkmark, Radio button, TreeViewItem, Expander ToggleButton glyphs -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlyphBrush" Color="#444"/>

    <Style x:Key="test" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <!-- The ToggleButton is databound to the ComboBox itself to toggle IsDropDownOpen -->
                    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="2" Template="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonControlTemplate1}" x:Name="ToggleButton" Focusable="false" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press"/>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,3,23,3" x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>

                    <!-- The TextBox must be named PART_EditableTextBox or ComboBox will not recognize it -->
                    <TextBox Visibility="Hidden" Template="{DynamicResource ComboBoxTextBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,3,23,3" x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Style="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Focusable="True" Background="Transparent" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>

                    <!-- The Popup shows the list of items in the ComboBox. IsOpen is databound to IsDropDownOpen which is toggled via the ComboBoxToggleButton -->
                    <Popup IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" Placement="Bottom" x:Name="Popup" Focusable="False" AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" x:Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="{DynamicResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource SolidBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1"/>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" Style="{DynamicResource SimpleScrollViewer}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True">

                                <!-- The StackPanel is used to display the children by setting IsItemsHost to be True -->
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"/>

                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <!-- This forces the DropDown to have a minimum size if it is empty -->
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="95" TargetName="DropDownBorder"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="AllowsTransparency" SourceName="Popup" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" TargetName="DropDownBorder"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0" TargetName="DropDownBorder"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox"/>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" TargetName="ContentSite"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ToggleButtonControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="Rectangle" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" Fill="{DynamicResource NormalBrush}" Stroke="{DynamicResource NormalBorderBrush}"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" Fill="{DynamicResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" Stroke="{DynamicResource NormalBorderBrush}"/>
        <Path Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="Arrow" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="Red" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource MouseOverBrush}" TargetName="Rectangle"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource PressedBrush}" TargetName="Rectangle"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" TargetName="Rectangle"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBorderBrush}" TargetName="Rectangle"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" TargetName="Arrow"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

To change the Shape or background of the Toggle Button in the example you have to modify the ControlsTemplate "ToggleButtonControlTemplate1".

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this!!! It helped me solve a problem I was running into!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use control templates for that.

Comment: They are quite complicated. you should start with pulling out the default control template of the standard combobox using a tool like XamlPadX and then modify the control template.